# AlarmManager is not cancelling android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to cancel my `alarmmanager` which I have registered before.
I am registering my `alarmmanager` as below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, GpsPingService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, 1545,
                                                            i, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
```

and i am trying to cancel it using following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, GpsPingService.class);
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, 1545, i, 0);
alarmManager.cancel(p);
```

But it's not cancelling. For debugging it I had putted this code in try catch block but it can't catch any error. Please let me know the reason why it's happening and how can I solve it?

## UPDATE

May be it is duplicate but i can not understand what is the difference between the answer which is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756653/android-how-to-cancel-an-alarm-alarmmanager-cancel-not-working) question and which i have tried. So, it's not duplicate question because i have already done the thing which is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756653/android-how-to-cancel-an-alarm-alarmmanager-cancel-not-working) answer.

## UPDATE 1

### Full Code

I am starting my service using following block of code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this);
                                    builder.setTitle("Need More Accuracy?");
                                    builder.setMessage("Hello user, you have set too small area for geofence. May be it will " +
                                            "perform action with delay in time. If you want to get more accuracy in action" +
                                            " then press \"YES\" button. More accuracy will consume more bettery then normal.");
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            startService(new Intent(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, GpsPingService.class));


                                            try {

                                                Intent i = new Intent(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, GpsPingService.class);
                                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, 1545,
                                                        i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.ALARM_SERVICE);

                                                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
                                                Log.e("JK-->> ", "Alarmmanager setted!");
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                Log.e("JK-->>", "Error gpsping register -->> " + e.toString());
                                            }

                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            try {
                                                Intent i = new Intent(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, GpsPingService.class);
                                                PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, 1545, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.ALARM_SERVICE);
                                                alarmManager.cancel(p);
                                                stopService(i);

                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                Log.e("JK-->>", "Cancel alarmmanager error-->> " + e.getMessage().toString());
                                            }
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                                    alertDialog.show();
```

Service class:

```
public class GpsPingService extends Service {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("JK-->>", "Gpsping Service stopped!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e("JK-->>", "Gpsping Service started!");
    }

    public GpsPingService() {
        Log.e("JK-->>", "constructor");
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("JK-->>", "Gpsping Service onstartcommand!");
        try {


            Intent i = new Intent(this, GpsPingService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1545,
                    i, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);


            locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                    .setInterval(1000)
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setFastestInterval(1000);

            LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    Log.e("JK-->>", "location updated by gpsping service-->> " + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude() +
                            " " + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };

            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("JK-->>Gpsping-->> ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, How to cancel an alarm? alarmManager.cancel not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756653/android-how-to-cancel-an-alarm-alarmmanager-cancel-not-working)

Comment: see updated question. @ReazMurshed

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a different `AlarmManager`;

```
Intent i = new Intent(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, GpsPingService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, 1545,i, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
```

And when you cancel it you do this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, GpsPingService.class);
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, 1545, i, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(p);
```

Doing this is working for me.

Comment: @Jaydip Kalkani, Can you tell me why are you using both startService and PendingIntent.getService?  PendingIntent.getService starts the Service but you are making a service call twice here. remove startService and check out if it works.

Comment: i'd tried it after reading your answer but it's not working @Black

Comment: My service is still running man....please help me to solve out this problem. it takes too much time to solve it for me. i am trying to solve it from today morning but it's still as it is...@Black

Answer (score 0):

I think you provide a wrong flag to `PendingIntent`. According [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))

> May be FLAG_ONE_SHOT, FLAG_NO_CREATE, FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, FLAG_IMMUTABLE or any of the flags as supported by Intent.fillIn() to control which unspecified parts of the intent that can be supplied when the actual send happens.

Try using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when you create alarm, then cancel it.

```
PendingIntent.getService(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this, 1545, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Also i see that you get context from service itself. Check context for `null`, or maybe is not running.

Comment: No, i had tried your suggestion but it doesn't works.

Comment: if you don't mind can you share my screen and try to solve out my problem?

Comment: Ok, let me update my question with full code. @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Comment: hey can i get answer from you? @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Comment: @Jaydip Kalkani, First can you let me what are you trying to achieve?  Where are you setting the alarm at first time(Activity, receiver or something else) & Why are you setting alarm inside the service? If in case you have referred some source to create this project please mention the link.

Comment: @Black yes, offcourse, i am just trying to retrieve location updates every 5 seconds. i know it can be achieved by just using service and just by starting it using startservice but in this there is a problem in xiomi devices. In those devices when i press clear all button from recent apps menu...it stops my service also. so i've to use alarmmanager for starting my service again after it stops

Comment: @Black I am setting my alarm first time in my activity and this code is putted in my question. and i am registering my alarm in service because in xiomi devices there is a problem with services as i mentioned above when i click clear all button in recent apps menu it clears my service....so,i am trying to restart service after every 5 seconds and hence i had put alarm in service and i have not reffered any project for this,

Comment: @ Jaydip Kalkani, Have you tested the same without setting alarm in Service class on the phones other than Xiaomi, If Yes, what is the status?

Comment: Please open a chat room and continue there. Thanks.

Comment: yes i have tested and it was working perfectly! now my problem is solved. i am very very thankful to you for your help. thanks a lot. @Black and sorry for desturbing but now chat is ended. thanks for support Florescu

Comment: @Jaydip Kalkani, Happy to hear it had helped.